# I have problem instaling libftdi on mysys2

Tags: c++, msys2, libftdi

I just want to instal libftdi on mysys2 to be able to compile and write some code
I have used this link and cmd line to do it
https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-libftdi
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libftdi

But I will get this errors

> File
> /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc-1.2.1-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is
> corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)). Do you want
> to delete it? [Y/n] y error: mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv: signature from
> "David Macek david.macek.0@gmail.com" is unknown trust :: File
> /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv-1.16-2-any.pkg.tar.zst
> is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)). Do you
> want to delete it? [Y/n] y error: mingw-w64-x86_64-confuse: signature
> from "David Macek david.macek.0@gmail.com" is unknown trust :: File
> /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-confuse-3.3-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
> is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)). Do you
> want to delete it? [Y/n] y error: failed to commit transaction
> (invalid or corrupted package) Errors occurred, no packages were
> upgraded.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a new MSYS2 installation? Try updaing it first (`pacman -Syuu`, then, if the terminal closes during update, restart it and run the same command again), then try again.

Comment: thanks for the tip, it seems it has install it, But I will get these new errors when try to compile some code Package libftdi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libftdi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

Comment: What MSYS2 environment are you running, i.e. what the magenta text says in the terminal prompt? It should be `MINGW64` and not `MSYS`. Run MSYS2 using the shortcut called `MSYS2 64-bit` to get the right environment. Make sure you installed GCC from the package called `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` and not `gcc`, and same for pkg-config.

Comment: I'm runing msys32 mingw64 and trying to compile this repo from git hub https://github.com/ribalda/ftdieeprom   I just fresh installed msys 2 64bit and then run pacman -Syuu command then run pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc and them I use  msys32 mingw64 and type make

Comment: Do you mean the environment is `MINGW64`, as indicated in the terminal prompt? You should also need `mingw-w64-x86_64-make` and `mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config`.

Comment: yes I mean MINGW64, How do I get or install mingw-w64-x86_64-make and mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config

Comment: I have tried this command pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config and I will get this error resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config and mingw-w64-x86_64-pkgconf are in conflict. Remove mingw-w64-x86_64-pkgconf? [Y/n] y
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing mingw-w64-x86_64-pkgconf breaks dependency 'mingw-w64-x86_64-pkgconf' required by mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake

Comment: You should be able to just do `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-make`. Weird error, but ok. What do `which pkg-config` and `pkg-config --list-all` print?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248844/discussion-between-asidesigner-and-holyblackcat).