# Ada Alire GNATColl_Postgres Installation failed

Tags: ada, msys2, gnatcoll

I am trying to get  gnatcoll_postgres into C:\GNColl_Postgresql using Alire on Windows 10. But the process failed while installing  mingw-w64-x86_64-postgresql.

The errors message are as follows:

```
error: mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc-1.2.1-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]
error: mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2-1.0.8-2-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]
error: mingw-w64-x86_64-termcap: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mingw-w64-x86_64-termcap-1.3.1-6-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
ERROR: Deployment of system package from platform software manager: mingw-w64-x86_64-postgresql to C:\GNColl_Postgresql\gnatcoll_postgres_23.0.0_adf8e40f\alire\cache\dependencies\postgresql_15.1.0_system failed
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue.  Thanks in advance.
Regards.     Angelo.

Comment: Probably some problem with msys2. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028961/i-have-problem-instaling-libftdi-on-mysys2